# Windows 10 update, Imagick php not working anymore

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server, imagemagick, php5, php.ini

Since the last update of Windows 10 (KB4016240), my xampp server does not launch any more imagick, it was working fine before this update.

Now when I start Apache from Xampp I get the error message:

*the procedure entry point PixelGetFuzz could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll*

So I thought it was a PATH Environment issue and I reinstalled Imagemagick with no success.

Imagemagick version (convert --version):

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.3-10 Q16 x86 2016-05-04 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 180040629
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pangocairo png ps rsvg tiff webp xml zlib
```

Xampp Control Panel version: 3.2.2

php version: 5.6.23

What can I do?

**Edit:** I uninstalled the update KB4016240 and I still have the problem. So this appeared maybe because I had to reboot my computer and to restart Apache. I don't do it often and maybe I changed something while Apache was running without restarting it.

Comment: Open the DLL in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), which shows all the exported functions of a DLL. Check whether PixelGetFuzz is listed.

Comment: Here is the result: http://www.cjoint.com/doc/17_04/GDArpPLumhc_errors-imagick-dll.jpg I have to find the good `php_imagick.dll` which correspond to my Imagemagick installation.

Comment: Did you find PixelGetFuzz if you scroll down that list?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help, it was because of GraphicsMagick. More info on my message I edited.

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it; you can answer your own question below and mark as solved to close this now!

Comment: Ok, done but I have the message "You can accept your own answer in 2 days". I don't have to forget to accept it on next Friday. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found and well stay close on your seat!

It was because of GraphicsMagick http://www.graphicsmagick.org/ which I installed last week after php Imagick, I didn't restarted Apache from this GraphicsMagick installation. So what I did is : I uninstalled GraphicsMagick, Imagemagick and I reinstalled Imagemagick, reput the file php_imagick.dll I was using.

And now, everything is working like a charm.

It was because of GraphicsMagick, how is it possible?